# Using AngularJS, how can I use a public variable in the DOM?

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS I am sending a user to a page that has a query string based on employees they selected on a previous page. I am logging this variable, `users`, correctly but I can't use it with an `ng-if` in the DOM. I want to use `ng-if` when `user.ID` from the DOM equals `user` from the JS.

The HTML is:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div class="ProfileSheet" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-if="user.ID == user">
      <h3 class="heading">User Profile</h3>
      <table id="Profile">
        <tr>
          <th>User</th>
          <td>{{user.Title}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th> User Admin ID</th>
          <td>{{user.ID}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br>

  </div>
</div>
```

The JS is:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q){

    var getQueryString = function (field, url){
        var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
        var reg = new RegExp('[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i');
        var string = reg.exec(href);
        return string ? string[1] : null;
    }

    var users = getQueryString('users', window.location.href)

   $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log(users);
  });
```

How can I make this work?

Bonus: How can I make the`ng-repeat` work if multiple users were selected. For example: if the query string returns users as 19, 21, and 25 the `ng-repeat` currently looks for a user ID of `19,21,25`. Not three separate items.

Comment: The controller is accessible from the view, you can do `this.users` in the HTML, then `MainCtrl.users` in the JS. Why do you need the `ng-if` though?

Comment: Your ID bonus question could be handled by splitting the resulting string on ',' so that var users will be an array in all cases (if you have a single value it's just an array of length 1). With your specific implementation of getQueryString you'll have to check to make sure `users` is not null.

Comment: @BenKolyaMansley When the page loads, it shows info for all users in the system. I want to show info only for users that are listed in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this with `$scope.selectedusers` and `ng-if="user.ID == selectedusers`. Using `$scope.users` resulted in errors probably from using `ng-repeat = "user in users"`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `$scope.users` instead of `var users`. The template code uses scope variables: what you call as `var_name` in your template is actually `$scope.var_name` in the controller.